# Can I disable Alt+Drag for some applications (under KDE/Kwin)?

Tags: virtualbox, kde, kwin

Like a lot of window managers, Kwin lets you move windows by holding <kbd>Alt</kbd> and dragging them with button 1 on your mouse. This is really great... Until you're in Virtualbox and you try to move a guest window and accidentally de-fullscreen Virtualbox and mess up all your icons on your desktop.

It's annoying. Is there a way to selectively turn it off? The Kwin actions dialogue doesn't seem to have anything for advanced settings.

[image]

Perhaps there's a way to make Virtualbox "eat" the Alt key when the mouse is over it? I'd be just as happy with a Virtualbox specific answer because that's the only scenario that *really* causes me grief.

Answer (score 1):

I do not think it can be solved the exact way you propose.

But you can "trap" the mouse pointer into the virtualbox window.
You need to use a key to release the mouse before you can use it again on the desktop.
See [su.SE: How do I trap the mouse pointer within a VirtualBox Guest OS?](https://superuser.com/questions/377861/how-do-i-trap-the-mouse-pointer-within-a-virtualbox-guest-os)

Another solution could be to replace the modifier key <kbd>Alt</kbd> by <kbd>Super</kbd>,
 which is often the "Windows" key.